# How to see the commands run by Gradle

Tags: android, gradle, build

I've created an Android module in Android Studio to create a home screen widget for including in a Delphi app. To do this I need to manually run part of the build process a second time via a manual build script. This script runs aapt to generate the R.java, then javac and dex to re-compile it with some additional modules, which works well.

However, the resulting app + widget doesn't work correctly and I suspect it's the R.java file not being complete. When I host the same widget in a native Java app, the resulting R.java generated by Gradle contains lots of additional items, which I believe may be the problem.

I'd like to see what the generateReleaseRFile Gradle task actually does - i.e. what terminal commands it runs, and, if it calls aapt, what parameters it passes into it so I can compare to my manual build script.

Does anyone know if this is possible?

Thanks!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Getting the aapt2 parameters of a gradle build?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50142708/getting-the-aapt2-parameters-of-a-gradle-build)